# xhtml2pdf в джанго

Tags: python, django

Есть код который помогает генерить пдф файлы в джанго. Подскажите, какую кодировку использовать вместо "ISO-8859-1", для создания pdf файла на украинском/русском языках.
Так же скажите, как сделать два-три языка в одном файле

utils.py

```
from io import BytesIO
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template

from xhtml2pdf import pisa

def fetch_pdf_resources(uri, rel):
    if uri.find(settings.MEDIA_URL) != -1:
        path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, uri.replace(settings.MEDIA_URL, ''))
    elif uri.find(settings.STATIC_URL) != -1:
        path = os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, uri.replace(settings.STATIC_URL, ''))
    else:
        path = None
    return path


def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(template.encode('UTF-8')), result, encoding='utf-8',link_callback=fetch_pdf_resources)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import View
from django.template.loader import get_template
from .utils import render_to_pdf

class GeneratePDF(View):
    def get(self, request, *arg, **kwargs):
        template = get_template('pdf_gen.html')
        context = {
            "customer_name": "John cooper",
            "amount": 123231,
            "today": "Today",
        }
        # html = template.render(context)
        # return    HttpResponse(html)
        html = template.render(context)
        pdf = render_to_pdf('pdf_gen.html' , context)
        if pdf:
            response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type = 'application/pdf')
            filename = "Invoice_%s.pdf" %("213231231")
            content = "inline; filename = '%s'" %(filename)
            response['Content-Disposition'] = content
            return response
        return  HttpResponse("Not found")
```

так как использования этого стандарта выдаёт ошибку

> 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 1251-1257: ordinal not in range(256)

сам html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            @font-face { font-family: Times New Roman; src: url("{% static 'css_styles/times-new-roman.ttf' %}"); }
            body{
              font-family: Times New Roman;
            }
            body {
                font-weight: 200;
                font-size: 14px;
            }
            .header {
                font-size: 20px;
                font-weight: 100;
                text-align: center;
                color: #007cae;
            }
            .title {
                font-size: 22px;
                font-weight: 100;
               /* text-align: right;*/
               padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;  
            }
            .title span {
                color: #007cae;
            }
            .details {
                padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
                text-align: left !important;
                /*margin-left: 40%;*/
            }
            .hrItem {
                border: none;
                height: 1px;
                /* Set the hr color */
                color: #333; /* old IE */
                background-color: #fff; /* Modern Browsers */
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='wrapper'>
            <div class='header'>
                <p class='title'>  </p>
            </div>
        <div>
        <div class='details'>
        ф
        івфівфівфівфіпкщенузхк
        ущзехцщузхе
            asdasd
            щзщзщз
            іівівфівфі
            <!-- <hr class='hrItem' /> -->
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Всегда и везде нужно использовать UTF-8. Убедитесь только, что используемый шрифт поддерживает символы юникода.

Comment: при Utf-8 выдаёт чёрные квадраты в pdf файле

Comment: Значит шрифт или не юникодный или не загрузился в процессе рендеринга.

Comment: Добавил код html Который я рендерю. МОжет в нём что то не так ?

Comment: https://toster.ru/q/536178

Comment: 'Template' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: Не нужно бездумно копировать. В вашем случае переменной `template` соответствует переменная `html`. Посмотрите как заданы шрифты в шаблоне и как определён колбэк для их загрузки в рендер.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97594/discussion-between-wilteratenau-and-sergey-gornostaev).